# Built in predicates prolog

Tags: prolog, predicate

So I was wondering which of the following are considered built in predicates in prolog.

- `,`
- `;`
- `|`
- `is`
- `+`

The thing is I need to write some prolog code without using any built in predicates.

Comment: Only is/2. But ask your prof to confirm you cannot use *numbers*

Comment: This is a ridiculous requirement. You cannot really do _anything_ without built-in predicates. Are you sure your instructor did not mean rather something like "do not use predicates from `library(lists)` or so?

Comment: I believe it was "using ONLY built-in predicates"..